# Xbox One Prismatic Afterglow controller unresponsive

Tags: controllers, xbox-one

So, I've had this controller for about 3 or 4 months, and recently my controller has had a strange problem where when I plug it in, it lights up the LEDs, and about 5 seconds later, it turns off. I've held down the button to turn it on, but the light that shows it's connected doesn't light up and is unresponsive. I've reset the controller and hard reset the Xbox one and it's still unresponsive.

Comment: It could just be bricked. More recent Amazon reviews aren't favorable with complaints of losing function and poor customer service for PDP, and the "professional" reviews rate it high but the user blogs tell a mixed story, many with similar issues.